# Clicked then goes Up, Click again, then goes down

Tags: c#, image, button, unity-game-engine

I have image w/ button component. I'm creating an Inventory-like, and i need it to be shown like a Paper Going up when clicked, and goes down when i clicked it again.

Here are the codes that can do automatically, can i do it manually. please help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BMM : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 pointB;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var pointA = transform.position;

            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0f));
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0f));

    }

    IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
    {
        var i = 0.0f;
        var rate = 1.0f / time;
        while (i < 1.0f)
        {
            i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
            thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this : http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MoveObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. If I understand correctly you want some kind of switch button, a switch button that goes up when clicked (switched on) and goes down when clicked again (switched off). If this is what you are trying to do, I would suggest something like this:

```
public class BMM : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public Vector3 pointB;
    private Vector3 pointA;

    private bool isClicked;

    void Start()
    {
        pointA = transform.position;
        isClicked= false;
    }

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (isClicked == false)
        {
            isClicked = true;
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0f));
        }
        else
        {
            isClicked = false;
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0f));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
    {
        var i = 0.0f;
        var rate = 1.0f / time;
        while (i < 1.0f)
        {
            i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
            thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `IPointerClickHandler` interface only works because your object has a `Button` component attached to it. If you remove the `Button` component it will not work.

Also once you type `IPointerClickHandler` in the top of the class, you can right-click on the name of the interface and the choose the option `Implicit Implement` (or something similar) and It will create the methods OnPointerClick for you.